# How Search component works in AEM?

Tags: java, content-management-system, adobe, aem, aem-6

what is the best way to implement Search Component in AEM. Can someone share any references on that. I am interested to  know the backend process(java) in Search Component. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: AEM is pretty much backed by the arcane indexing engine called [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/), adobe had plenty of explanation on [their website](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-cloud-service/content/operations/indexing.html?lang=en). i'm personally unsure how to answer your question as we might need to revisit Information Retrieval class.

Answer (score 0):

Search in AEM is supported by [querybuilder api](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/developing/platform/query-builder/querybuilder-api.html?lang=en), see aem [core search component](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/tree/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/search/v1/search) for a reference implementation. also [see documentation](https://www.adobe.com/go/aem_cmp_search_v1).

Answer (score 0):

Search Component is already available in AEM OOTB. They use a full-text search.
It depends on your requirements, which search component you can use.

If you're interested in the back-end process of the search component, it uses queries on the back-end.
You can create a similar component to which is provided by AEM.
The queries would be as follows:

**QueryBuilder URL**: ( http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html )

**Query:**

path : <*path_under_which_to_search*>

fulltext : "*string to be searched*"

fulltext.relPath = ./

This above query will search "string to be searched" under <path_under_which_to_search>, how it will search depends on the relPath.
If you keep relPath empty, that is how OOTB search works , it will search node names under a location.
If you keep relPath : jcr:content/@cq:tags, it will search cq:tags property of every node under the location.
If you keep relPath : ./ , it will search all the JCR properties under the location.

**Query Cheatsheet** : https://github.com/paulrohrbeck/aem-links/blob/master/querybuilder_cheatsheet.md